# Javascript detecting whether User on Chrome is logged in

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, security

[image]

so when you're on Chrome you can login to your Google account to save and sync browser data

Is there any way that a site can use Javascript code to detect that? Or even call a library to detect it?

Answer (score 1):

No. It would be a **massive** security/privacy issue.

*(Granted, the web has had those before, but if this were one, it would have been closed by now.)*

Answer (score 1):

No, like mentioned in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77624931/1697459).

But maybe good to mention that it's possible the other way around: Your Chrome browser can detect that the 3rd party site (or app) you are visiting supports login with Chrome and could show a Google account sign in prompt.

[image]

Read [here for more details on that feature](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/12849458?sjid=3176755813211986543-EU).
This prompting feature can be disabled [here](https://myaccount.google.com/connections/settings?pli=1).